# What is the difference between int and integer in MySQL 5.0?

Tags: mysql, types, integer

What is the difference between int and integer datatypes in MySQL 5.0? Can anyone help? I don't understand the exact difference.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Taken from [MYSQL 5.0 online reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

The keyword INT is a synonym for INTEGER.

Comment: Just adding that also applies to versions 3.23, 4.X and 5.X (at the momment 5.7 is last version)

Answer (score 16):

I guess the only difference is the spelling.

So by using INT, you'd end up using less bytes on your SQL script (not that it matters).

Answer (score 14):

According to the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html) :

> The keyword INT is a synonym for INTEGER

but if you want to write SQL scripts compatible with [ANSI SQL](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) use `INTEGER`. According to the [specification](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) :

> SQL defines distinct data types named by the following keywords:
>            CHARACTER, CHARACTER VARYING, BIT, BIT VARYING, NUMERIC, DECIMAL,
>            **INTEGER**, SMALLINT, FLOAT, REAL, DOUBLE PRECISION, DATE, TIME,
>            TIMESTAMP, and INTERVAL.

In this way, you will have better chance to use your SQL scripts on other DBMS. For example [PostgresSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html) have an `INTEGER` type but no `INT` type.

Comment: [SQL-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) did mention that "INT is equivalent to INTEGER" in chapter 6 so I guess `INT` is also a part of the standard. Don't know why PostgreSQL have no `INT` type though.

Comment: @weeix SQLite doesn't have `INT` either. It uses `INTEGER`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `int` and integer is that `int` is a data type, but integer is a group of data types – e.g. `int`, `long`, `short` and `byte`.