# What is the difference between Int and Integer datatypes in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using `Int` and `Integer` datatypes in my stored procedures, both behaviors are looking same.

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 14):

There is no difference between the 2. A quick look at the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258273(v=sql.80).aspx) shows that `integer` is a data type synonym for `int`. Note that while this link is for SQL Server 2000, the answer remains valid all the way till SQL Server 2014.

Comment: This URL is obsolete

Comment: The equivalent URL for the current documentation is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-synonyms-transact-sql

Answer (score 2):

They are the same thing.

Source:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Duplicate:[What is the difference between int and integer in MySQL 5.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688582/what-is-the-difference-between-int-and-integer-in-mysql-5-0)

EDIT: From shree.pat18, I'm being an idiot and I put MySQL documentation instead of SQL server since is was reading too fast.

Microsoft says they are the same thing as well. As shree.pat18 said, MySQL and SQL have similar documentation and to a lesser extend SQLite, cheers.

Comment: Why are you providing MySQL links for a question tagged with SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry as a quick google I got them confused. I'll delete the link.

Comment: Don't delete. Just add in the SQL Server ones, and mention that MySQL follows the same principle. That will make it better :)

Comment: We're trying hard not to use any links to ispirer, since they posted spam on SO in the past.  Could you use a link to the official documentation instead?